# Why is a negative value after hash?

Tags: c#

Can someone please advise, why after computed hash, stores a negative value to e?

```
static byte[] bytes;
BigInteger[] numbers = {A, ANeg, Aseed, AseedNeg, C1, C2, C1Neg, C2Neg};
foreach (BigInteger number in numbers)
{
    bytes = number.ToByteArray();
}
SHA1 sha = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
e = new BigInteger(hash);
```

Comment: It depends on the highest bit of generated hash, isnt it?

Comment: Are you trying to convert the hash back to a BigInteger?  You can't do that.

Comment: This `BigInteger` constructor is well documented -- if the highest bit is 1, the resulting number is negative. But it's also meaningless: a SHA1 hash is not a number any more than a block of encrypted text is. It's just a bunch of bytes, to which you are giving a "meaning" of your choice.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason "-3" is negative and "2" isn't; the symbol used to indicate the number is below zero is there: In the case of someone writing down "-3" this is "-". In the case of a BigInteger, this is the most significant bit.

Answer (score 0):

The [`BigInteger(byte[])` constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN offers the following:

> if the highest-order bit of the highest-order byte in value is set, the resulting BigInteger value is negative

and

> To prevent positive values from being misinterpreted as negative values, you can add a zero-byte value to the end of the array.

Applying the documentation:

1. `e` will be negative if the last byte in `hash` (i.e., `hash[hash.Length - 1]`) is greater than 0x7f (127).
2. To interpret the value of `hash` as an unsigned number, add a zero-byte value to the end of `hash`, e.g.,

   ```
   e = new BigInteger(hash.Concat(new byte[]{0}).ToArray());
   ```